# How to get All Dimension names from Endeca pipeline

Tags: dimension, endeca

I have three level dimenions in my pipeline.. I have to get all the dimension namess including child dimensions..  like Dimension tree with hirarchy.

I tried using dimenion search passing * but I did not get any results back.. If I use specific charcters then I am getting the search resuts..

I really appriciate your help.

Comment: Are you trying to get your entire category hierarchy extracted? By default Endeca will only return two levels of dimensions so you'll need to traverse each one of the nodes on your hierarchy yourself. It is quite simple, what is the name of your top level node in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found out the problem.  By default, many of the reference apps released recently have --compoundDimSearch defined for Dgidx (for instance, in the /config/script/DataIngest.xml file).  If you remove that, then the D=* queries will start working.

Also removing compoundDimSearch will typically result in a faster baseline update and smaller index size, so that's fun too.